# iframe correctly loads a webpage in some browsers but not others (insecure content error)

Tags: iframe, https, content-security-policy

I have an https website that is trying to display an external https webpage in an iframe.

On Chrome and Firefox for desktop, it loads fine.

On desktop/mobile Safari and mobile Chrome for iOS, it doesn't load anything.

In Safari I see the error:

```
The page at about:blank was not allowed to display insecure content from http://example.com
```

Although the webpage that the iframe loads is https, it looks like there is some content it is trying to load that is http, and blocks the iframe from loading anything.

I'm really stumped, because it works for some browsers, but not for others. Here are the browser tests I ran.

```
Desktop Chrome: Success
Desktop Firefox: Success
Desktop Safari: Fail
iOS Mobile Safari: Fail
iOS Mobile Chrome: Fail
Android Mobile Chrome: Success
```

Has anyone encountered this error before and knows how to get around it? Why does it work in some browsers but not others? I am striving for cross-browser compatibility with using iframe. Any suggestions for hacks or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
After looking into the network tab. I see that it's requesting an HTTPS url, but the location is a HTTP url. Some browsers are okay with this and show the content. Other browsers seem to block it. Even though the location url says http, the request url does in fact open an https website.
[image: network dev tools]

Comment: Is ```http://example.com``` the actual error message? What is the iFrame trying to load from ```http://example.com```? Also, when you open dev-tools, does the Chrome version also try to load content from ```http://example.com``` when checking ```network``` tab

Comment: No, the actual website has a different url. I changed to "example" because it wasn't important. But looking in the network tab did offer some insight. Check out this screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/221PdYP.png Apparently, it is requesting a HTTPS url but the location is a HTTP url. Chrome and Firefox are okay with this, but other browsers are not. Any idea why this is? For what it's worth, if you open the request url, it does in fact open a HTTPS site.

Comment: It looks like a redirect. The HTTP response of ```302 (Object Moved)``` forces the browser to load the HTTP site as listed in ```Location``` header. Looking at the network tab, it looks like the first link redirects 3 times before it gets to a proper ```200``` response code. If you have access to whatever is calling the first URL, perhaps change it to only call the final URL.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the URLs. Do you know why some browsers are okay with display the website in the iframe but other browsers block it?

Comment: Try setting [`referrerpolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-referrerpolicy) attribute to `no-referrer`? `<iframe referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="...">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is *mixed content* which is when you're loading HTTP and HTTP*S* content.

The first question you must ask yourself which most developers fail to do: is this worth doing?

Under the presumption that it is you're going to have to get creative. You'll basically have to have your `iframe` load a page from your own site and have *it* load non-HTTPS pages. That *also* implies having to scan for HTML/XML attributes such as `src` and reconstructing their URLs (don't forget about the `base` element) so that those images are served *through your site*.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url']))
{
 $url = $_GET['url'];
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $data;
}
?>
```